# sending mail in contact information with c#.net problem? help please

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendmail

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string ad = TextBox1.Text;
 string firma = TextBox2.Text;
 string mail = TextBox3.Text;
 string tel = TextBox4.Text;
 string tel2 = TextBox5.Text;
 string fax = TextBox6.Text;
 string fax2 = TextBox7.Text;
 string web = TextBox8.Text;
 string mesaj = TextBox9.Text;

 try 
 {
  string fromAddress = "user@gmail.com";
  string fromName = "user";
  string toMail = "user@gmail.com";
  string toNme = "Mr.";
  string msgSubject = "Contact";
  string sifre = "userpassword";

  string msgBody = "you have a message; \n"
  + "\n"
  + "\n"
  + "Mesaj? Gonderenin Ad? :" + ad + "\n"
  + "Mesaj? Gonderen Firma :" + firma + "\n"
  + "Mesaj? Gonderenin Maili :" + mail + "\n"
  + "Mesaj? Gonderenin Tel. Numaras? :" + tel + tel2 + "\n"
  + "Mesaj? Gonderenin Fax Numaras? :" + fax + fax2 + "\n"
  + "Mesaj? Gonderenin Web Adresi :" + web + "\n"
  + "\n"
  + "\n"
  + "" + mesaj + ""
  + "\n"
  + "\n"
  + "=======================================" + "\n";

  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
  client.Credentials = 
  new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromAddress, sifre);
  client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  client.Port = 1772;
  client.EnableSsl = false;
  MailAddress from = new MailAddress(fromAddress, fromName);
  MailAddress to = new MailAddress(toMail, toNme);
  MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

  message.Subject = msgSubject;
  message.Body = msgBody;

  client.Send(message);
  Response.Redirect("iletisim.aspx");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 }
}
```

and WEB.CONFIG

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="user@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="1772" defaultCredentials="false"
            userName="user" password="userpassword"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

i am on my web site's contact, and i fill some textbox and i click send button. later i open user@gmail.com account but i didnt receive contact information mail.. Where do I make a mistake??

Comment: Do you actually understand that you post your login/pass here? Change you password immediately! And never show it!

Comment: I hope that is not really your live username and password included.  Also, posting what the error you are getting would be helpful in figuring out how to fix your problem.

Comment: i am on my web site's contact, and i fill some textbox and i click send button. later i open user@gmail.com account but i didnt receive contact information mail.. Where do I make a mistake??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send a simple email using this snippet:

```
    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            "yourusername@gmail.com", 
            "yourpassword"
        ),
        EnableSsl = true
    };
    smtpClient.Send("from@gmail.com", "to@gmail.com", "subject", "body");
```

Assuming, `yourusername@gmail.com` and `yourpassword` are your username and password on google.

The differences from your code are the port `587` (instead of your `1772`) and use of `SSL` (`EnableSsl = true`).

Comment: thanx alex but i cant do it, Can you write clearly according to my Button2_Click

Comment: @ilkdrl, replace your `try...catch` block with a snippet I provided. If it works, the only thing to do is to change port and enable SSL. If it doesn't it would be good you to post some additional info (error or so).

Comment: thaks alex but again i cant do it..
i have a mistake in line 
smtpClient.Send("user@gmail.com", "user@gmail.com", "subject", "body");